# What's the different between a constructor & method in Python, can I mix them together?

Tags: python, plugins, frameworks, methods, constructor

I implemented a plugable framework like below.

It works but I'm confused about the implementation of Plugin2. Seems it uses a normal method instead of a class constructor.

Can I do so? Is there any cons?

Is it a normal-used 'pattern'? If it is, what's the pattern name? 'Duck typing'? Should I avoid usage like this?

UPDATE: My concern is for below method:

```
def addPlugin(name, plugin)
```

Now parameter plugin could be either a Class or a Method. Then it is kind of obscure for the plugin developer. Is this a common case in dynamic programming language world?

```
class MyFramework(object):
   _plugins = {}
   _osType = None
   @staticmethod
   def addPlugin(name, plugin):
      MyFramework._plugins[name]= plugin

   def __init__(self, osType):
      self._osType = osType
      for name, plugin in MyFramework._plugins.items():
         setattr(self, name, plugin(self, self._osType))

class Plugin1(object):
   def __init__(self, owner, osType):
      self.owner= owner
      self.osType = osType
   def hello(self):
      print 'this is plugin1'

def Plugin2(owner, osType):
   if (osType == "Linux"):
      return Plugin2Linux(owner)
   else:
      return Plugin2Common(owner)

class Plugin2Linux(object):
   def __init__(self, owner):
      self.owner= owner
   def hello(self):
      print 'this is plugin2 Linux version'

class Plugin2Common(object):
   def __init__(self, owner):
      self.owner= owner
   def hello(self):
      print 'this is plugin2 common version'

MyFramework.addPlugin("plugin1", Plugin1)
MyFramework.addPlugin("plugin2", Plugin2)

framework = MyFramework("Linux")

plugin1 = getattr(framework, "plugin1")
plugin2 = getattr(framework, "plugin2")

plugin1.hello()
plugin2.hello()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an often-used pattern called a [factory function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28software_concept%29). It's a good idea to have your interface open to any callable that returns an object, whether the callable is a function or a class. It keeps you flexible for whatever you want to do in the future.

Comment: Yes, it do be a factory function. but considering below method:

   def addPlugin(name, plugin):

Now plugin could be either a Class or a Method. Then it is kind of obscure for the plugin developer. They might ask, should I pass a Class or Method in?

I believe a framework should be clear and precise. Above case obviously not a good sample.

Comment: It's not a method--it's a function. (A method is a function that is a class attribute, such as `Plugin1.hello`.) The correct term for an object that can be called is a "callable," which will include functions, classes, and any object with a `__call__()` method. I'd probably specify a callable in the docs. If you don't want to get into that level of complexity in your documentation, it's easy enough to specify that it is a class, and the ability to pass other callables can be an undocumented bonus.

Answer (score 0):

Plugin2 is a module function that returns an object while Plugin1 is a class itself and return an instantiation of itself.

This is fine, though Python's recommended coding standard would have you lowercase function names (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), so it would be plugin2

For consistency, I'd also use a module function for plugin1 to keep things similar in case your implementation evolves.

Comment: I'm sorry, what's meaning about 'module function'? Create a module for each plugin? Or something else?

Comment: I just meant a function not part of a class inside the file your classes are defined in.  I referred to the file as a module, but maybe that's not right.